# TYPO3 v10: Overwrite locale from site configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have a german website with locale `de_DE` configured in the site configuration.

On one specific page I want to have locale `en_EN`.

Is it possible to overwrite the locale via TypoScript or any other way?

The TypoScript setting `config.locale_all` has been removed in v10.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible by reading the code. Since version 10, the locale is set in the middleware `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\SiteResolver` with

```
if ($routeResult->getLanguage() instanceof SiteLanguage) {
   Locales::setSystemLocaleFromSiteLanguage($routeResult->getLanguage());
}
```

If you register a custom middleware which is loaded after that one and before the next critical ones (or you could also xclass that one), you should be possible to check the page and change the locale.